# Rails: How to control how Date field is rendered in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

My object got by default today's date:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @obj.my_date = Date.today
  end
end
```

and then, in my "new object" form it is displayed like this:

```
<%= f.text_field(:my_date) %>
```

It looks like this: `2011-02-24`

I guess it is because of the default `to_s` method of `Date`.

Is that possible to render it like `24/02/2011` without overriding the `to_s` method of `Date` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done using [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

So in your locale:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      slashes: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

And in your view:

```
<%= l Date.today, :format => :slashes %>
```

Comment: Didn't know this. Always ended up monkey patching the `Date`/`Time` class with a method like `format`.

Comment: Yes Chirantan, you can achieve the same with Date.today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"). However, since dates are often formatted differently in different languages, it makes sense to use internationalization.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the point. I would like to use `f.text_field(..)`. to create an input text field where user enters a date. How should I pre-populate this input field with today's date using `i18n` ?

Comment: It's problematic in my case because I use the same form for "new" and "edit", so the initial value is `Date.today` in "new" and something else in "edit". Therefore, I can't hard code the today's date value in the view. The initial value should be controlled by the Controller.

Comment: Sorry Misha, then @obj.my_date = I18n.l(Date.today, :format => :slashes)

Comment: That's a possible solution. However, it was cleaner if I could save in `@obj.my_date` a `Date` object rather than `String`.

Comment: Then what's wrong with `text_field :value => l(Date.today, :format => :slashes)`? You can replace `Date.today` with whatever `Date` object you want.